# Something triggers a keyboard click constantly (Even in the BIOS), how do i find out what it is?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I was just playing some Call of Duty when the game suddenly crashed. I Ctrl + Alt + Deleted and and closed the process. While doing that i noticed something seemed weird, cause some elements in the TaskManager got focused by itself.

At first i thought it was my keyboard, so i unplugged it and plugged in another one that i know works. Then i restarted the computer, only to find out i couldn't login, because something was constantly pushing a button (or sending button clicks so to speak). I should mention that i have my computer set up so that it automatically logins to my main account, and then run a file that locks the computer. So something on my main account is running in the background and constantly sending button clicks.

I have no idea what is causing this. I just logged in to my guest account, where everything works as it should. How should i go about to find out what's causing this? I don't have admin access from my guest account, but i guess i could login through safe mode if nessesary?

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit.

**Update:**

I figured out that if i press the "Switch user" button and then click the main account again, i can login without problems. Still don't know what's causing it though.

**Update:**

I restarted the computer into safe mode and i have the same problem there. When i tried to get to the startup option page (to boot into safe mode) i accidentally pressed F12 which got me to another page. That page had an input field, and i noticed lots of spaces were spammed there too. So what is going on?

Comment: A key is stuck down? Possibly spacebar?

Comment: That's the first thing i thought of. Hence the changed keyboard. I don't think i have two keyboards with the same problem. I'm 100% sure i don't actually, cause i've used this one before. Please see my updated post below. This is crazy...

Comment: What exactly is this "file that locks the computer"?

Comment: I have one of these (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13278-lock-computer-create-shortcut.html) shortcuts in the startup folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that it's related to a usb-device, try to unplug everything including mouse and keyboard and see if there is still a problem when you try to unlock the computer again.

Comment: I've tried that too. I'll give it another shot though, hang on.

Comment: Oh man, i feel so stupid now. I tried it before, but i guess i didn't notice those two USB's on the back (but i pulled out everything else on the back). I have another office in my house with the same computer, so i just have double keyboards installed to it. Turns out there was a blanket laying on the spacebar in the other office. I was freaking out here! Oh well, thanks!